# Ansible playbook put find exhaust to text file with sed

Tags: ansible

How to start a playbook when pulling a playbook and insert it into the config? for example in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

need to insert this

```
fastcgi_pass unix: /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

How to insert for example 7.1 or 7.2 instead of 7.0 if the PHP versions will differ?

---

Partially found the solution using find, but how now to insert the result of find into the file?

I use the command: `find /var/run/php/ -name *.sock`

exhaust such: `/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`

Now this case should be inserted into the file by sed

Comment: Hi user3558285, welcome to SO. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with especial emphasis on the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) part. You have not said what you have already tried, or whether there is an existing `fastcgi_pass` line in the file, or anything that would help us to help you. Show what you have tried, and show its errors; that helps demonstrate that you have put in some effort, versus "do my work for me"

Comment: i just wanna find the way how to put find exhaust result to file, because it's depends of PHP version.

Comment: I encourage you to re-read my comment, and to read those two links. I didn't ask you what you _wanted_. I asked you what you have _already tried_. With emphasis on **show that you have put in some effort**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html)

```yaml
  - shell: "php -n -v | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d '.' -f 1,2"
    register: php_version
  - lineinfile:
      path: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
      regexp: "^fastcgi_pass unix:"
      line: "fastcgi_pass unix: /var/run/php/php{{ php_version.stdout }}-fpm.sock;"
```